# How do I do a CR-type formula in SQL Server Reporting services?

Tags: crystal-reports, ssrs-2008

In Crystal Reports, I could define a formula that would evaluate for each detail line. For example, if I had a query that would return a PatientId, an ObsTerm name, and an ObsTerm value, I could define a formula called {@Hispanic} that had the value:

```
If {Command.OBSNAME} = "HISPANIC" Then
    {Command.OBSVALUE}
Else
    " "
```

Then, in the group footer, I could take Maximum({@Hispanic}, {Command.PATIENTID}) to see if I had gotten a value returned for the patient's ethnicity - either I'd get the value (assume only one, since that's how I built the query) or a blank.

I'm trying to convert a CR report over to SSRS 2008R2: how would I do the above? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a calculated field to your data source (called 'Hispanic' or whatever) with a formula of:

```
=IIF(Fields!OBSNAME.Value="Hispanic",Fields!OBSVALUE.Value,"")
```

In your report, add a parent group to your detail row and type [Max(Hispanic)] into a field in the group row. You may then want to hide the detail row and show only the aggregate data. I think there's probably a much easier way to do what you want but it's not clear from your question.

I made the transition from Crystal to SSRS and it is a hard road. You need to unlearn all your Crystal (especially formatting).

Comment: Lovely. That answers the question I asked just fine. I have a follow-on question: This report is pulling data from three places to get one answer, for historical reasons. In the group footer expression, I have    

 (Instr(Iif(Not IsNothing(Max(Fields!Ethnicity.Value, "PatientId"))
    , Max(Fields!Ethnicity.Value, "PatientId")
    , Iif(Max(Fields!obsEthnicity.Value, "PatientId") > " "
        , Max(Fields!obsEthnicity.Value, "PatientId")
        , Max(Fields!obsHispanic.Value, "PatientId")
    )
 ), "Non") > 0)

repeated 5 times. Any way to simplify that? If so, I'll post a new question.